# How RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper (django admin) loads the created content

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm building a webpage that use ModelForm with ManyToMany relations. The Admin of django has the useful RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper. It creates a + next to relationfields that, when pressed, opens a popup to create a related-object. Once the creation is made the main webpage (the one where we press the +) has the new item loaded.

Now, in my website I would like to have something similar, my questions are:

- is it correct to use the RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper in a webpage outside admin?
- how does the page autoloads the new content (this is mainly my curiosity)
- any other applicable solution to have a handy form without requiring complex JS or several pages?

thanks